# Браузер выдает ошибку 404 файлам, которых нет

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я столкнулся с проблемой: в Vs code у меня бутсрэп файлы не подключены, в вот браузер думает по другому, и выдаёт ошибки по несуществующим файлам(на фото видно), у меня были они подключённы(бутсрэп файлы), но позже я их удалил, но файл в браузере остался старым, что делать? Может я что то не так сделал?

Comment: почисть кэш браузера и сохрани свои файлы... ато может ты ctrl+s не нажал

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что на экране не самая последняя версия файла, судя по подсвеченной строке во временной шкале.

Comment: @void, ну не факт, там мог находится курсор во время скриншота.